# FQL like, share, comment count accuracy

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Often it seems fql number for a given url like, share, comment, total counts seem to be off.

For example this url

http://www.france24.com/en/20140112-reporters-crimean-tatars-unending-exile-identity-ethnic-minority-muslims-central-asia-ukraine

FQL shows:

```
share_count: 18377
like_count: 16215
comment_count: 8840
total_count: 43432
```

The graph api shows very different numbers, and if you check facebook widget count on the url itself it has a totally different count.

Anyone knows what is going on and how to get accurate numbers.

Comment: Never used any of the facebook stuff, but different results would suggest to me like some sort of data caching. Much like how [stack exchange data queries work](http://data.stackexchange.com/) (notice the `"last updated yesterday"` part... just speculation mind, but might give you an idea for something to search for

Comment: _“FQL shows”_ – no, i doesn’t. Results I’m getting for that URL from the FQL `link_stat` table, the Graph API and the total count shown in the official Like button are consistent – and _way_ lower than the figures you have shown (a total count of 77 as of right now). No idea where you are getting _your_ numbers from …

Comment: Thank you, CBroe are you checking the url as I posted it? without / at the end of the url? if you add / to the ending you will get 77 as the widget shows. without / the total for me link_stat table shows 43532 .

Comment: If anyone can shed a light on this I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When querying `link_stat` with url you supplied we see the following:

```
select comment_count, like_count, share_count, total_count 
  from link_stat where url = 'http://www.france24.com/en/20140112-reporters-crimean-tatars-unending-exile-identity-ethnic-minority-muslims-central-asia-ukraine/'
```

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "comment_count": 10, 
      "like_count": 55, 
      "share_count": 18, 
      "total_count": 83
    }
  ]
}
```

But when querying `link_stat` with parent url of site france24.com we see exactly your numbers (weel slightly changed of course, but almost the same). So check you query - maybe you cut the url somehow in you request?

```
select comment_count, like_count, share_count, total_count 
  from link_stat where url = 'http://www.france24.com/'
```

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "comment_count": 8840, 
      "like_count": 16415, 
      "share_count": 18377, 
      "total_count": 43632
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi user15, thank you. yes with / at the end of the url those are the numbers. The issue was with the url without  / at the end, like this http://www.france24.com/en/20140112-reporters-crimean-tatars-unending-exile-identity-ethnic-minority-muslims-central-asia-ukraine

Comment: is there an alternative to fql (as fql will not work for versions above 2) for the same question. Is there an api which gives the same output?

Comment: @sudil you should look into facebook insights https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/insights but it's kind of overcomplicated for me

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps my initial question was not clear, the issue was with 2 forms of the same url returning radically different results in fql, web facebook widget etc. the urls in question are

http://www.france24.com/en/20140112-reporters-crimean-tatars-unending-exile-identity-ethnic-minority-muslims-central-asia-ukraine

and

http://www.france24.com/en/20140112-reporters-crimean-tatars-unending-exile-identity-ethnic-minority-muslims-central-asia-ukraine/

The URLs are identical except the ending /

Answer (score 0):

The facebook sees the url as a string. Is case sensitive and it matters how you pass it for url. So, for facebook, there are really two different urls :/ The same happens if someone writes Ukraine with "U".

http://www.france24.com/en/20140112-reporters-crimean-tatars-unending-exile-identity-ethnic-minority-muslims-central-asia-Ukraine